# after setstate ui is not changing in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am making a simple app and I want to show and hide reply of particular comment on button pressed of respective comment.
But the UI is not changing after the state is changing.
How to solve this issue ,suggest me an idea and thanks in advance.
The snapchatReply list have commentId and isShown field,I want to toggle based on isShown value.

```
 toggleReply(String commentId){
       for(int a=0;a<snapchatReply.length;a++){
           print(snapchatReply.length);
              if(commentId==snapchatReply[a]['commentId']){
                 if(snapchatReply[a]['isShown']==false){
                setState(() {
                   snapchatReply[a]['isShown']=true;
                });
              }
              else{
                print("else");
                setState(() {
                  snapchatReply[a]['isShown']=false;
                 });
              }
              }
            }
       print(snapchatReply); 
       

  
  }
```

It give following outpit:

```
2
I/flutter ( 8112): 2
I/flutter ( 8112): [{commentId: 6312c32e842444a707b6903f, isShown: true}, {commentId: 6318257479bcbf779df08816, isShown: false}]
I/flutter ( 8112): 4
I/flutter ( 8112): else
I/flutter ( 8112): 4
I/chatty  ( 8112): uid=10154(com.example.fbclone) 1.ui identical 1 line
I/flutter ( 8112): 4
I/flutter ( 8112): [{commentId: 6312c32e842444a707b6903f, isShown: false}, {commentId: 6318257479bcbf779df08816, isShown: false}, {commentId: 6312c32e842444a707b6903f, isShown: true}, {commentId: 6318257479bcbf779df08816, isShown: false}]



    Full code:
ListView.builder(
                itemCount: widget.snapshot.comments.length,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (context, j) {
                
                  commentLike.add({"index":j,
                  "like":widget.snapshot.comments[j].commentlikes.length,
                  "commentId":widget.snapshot.comments[j].id});
                  
                  snapchatReply.add({
                    "commentId":widget.snapshot.comments[j].id,
                    "isShown":false
                    });
                
                  return SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width-150,
                      child: Card(
                        child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              IconButton(
                                  iconSize: 50,
                                  onPressed: () {},
                                  icon: CircleAvatar(
                                    radius: 80,
                                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                        widget.snapshot.comments![j].user.profile),
                                  )),
                              Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 100,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                          color: Colors.grey[300]),
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                      child: Column(
                                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: [
                                            Text(
                                              widget.snapshot.comments![j].user.name,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 18,
                                                  color: Colors.black,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                            ),
                                            Text(widget.snapshot.comments![j].commentText),
                                            
                                            // Text(widget.snapshot.comments![j].commentText,
                                            //     style: TextStyle(
                                            //         fontSize: 16,
                                            //         color: Colors.grey[700])),
                                          ])),
                                    Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Text(convertToAgo(
                                            widget.snapshot.comments![j].commentAt)),
                              
                                        TextButton(
                                            onPressed: () {
                                              likeComment(
                                                widget.snapshot.comments![j].id,
                                                widget.postId,
                                                );
                                            },
                                            child: Text("Like", style: myStyle)),
                                        TextButton(
                                          onPressed: () {
                                              print("isReply");
                                            setState(() {
                                              isReply=true;
                                              commentId=widget.snapshot.comments![j].id;
                                              userName=widget.snapshot.comments![j].user.name;
                                            });
                                           
                                          },
                                          child: Text("Reply", style: myStyle),
                                        ),
                                        TextButton(onPressed: (){
                                            toggleReply(widget.snapshot.comments![j].id);
                                        
                                        },
                                        child: Text("view reply"),
                                        ),
                                        if(widget.snapshot.comments![j].commentlikes!.length!=0)...[
                                          if(commentLike[j]['like']!=0)...[
                                          Text(totalLikes(commentLike[j]['like']))
                                          ]
                                        ],
                                        //  Text(totalLikes(widget.snapshot.comments![j].commentlikes!.length),
                                        //         style: myStyle),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    
                                    
                                     reply(snapchatReply: snapchatReply, snapshot: widget.snapshot.comments[j])
                                ],
                              ),
                            ]),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                
                }),
```

reply.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class reply extends StatefulWidget {
  const reply({Key? key,required this.snapchatReply,required this.snapshot}) : super(key: key);
final snapshot;
final snapchatReply;
  @override
  State<reply> createState() => _replyState();
}

class _replyState extends State<reply> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
                                 children:[
                                    for (int k = 0;k < widget.snapshot.reply!.length;k++) ...[
                                      for(int l=0;l<widget.snapchatReply.length;l++) ...[
                                         if(widget.snapchatReply[l]["commentId"]==widget.snapshot.id && widget.snapchatReply[l]["isShown"]==true) ...[
                                
                                    Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: [
                                          IconButton(
                                              iconSize: 50,
                                              onPressed: () {},
                                              icon: CircleAvatar(
                                                radius: 80,
                                                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(widget.snapshot.reply![k].user.profile),
                                              )),
                                          Column(
                                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                              children: [
                                                Container(
                                                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width -200,
                                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                        borderRadius:
                                                            BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                                        color: Colors.grey[300]),
                                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                                    child: Column(
                                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                                            MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                                        crossAxisAlignment:
                                                            CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                                        children: [
                                                          Text(
                                                            widget.snapshot
                                                                .reply![k].user.name,
                                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                                fontSize: 18,
                                                                color: Colors.black,
                                                                fontWeight:
                                                                    FontWeight.bold),
                                                          ),
                                                           RichText(
                                                                  text: TextSpan(
                                                                      style: TextStyle( fontSize:18,color:Colors.grey[700],fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                                                      children: <TextSpan>[
                                                                        TextSpan(text:widget.snapshot.user.name + " ", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                                                                        
                                                                        TextSpan(text:widget.snapshot.reply[k].replyText,style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal) ),
                                                                      ],
                                                                  ),
                                                                ),
                                                        ])),
                                                         
                                                               ])
                                                  ])
                                    ]
                                      
                                      ]
                                      
                                      
                                      ]
                                    ],
      
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: could you please include sample of what inside the snapchatReply is?

Comment: [{commentId: 6312c32e842444a707b6903f, isShown: false}, {commentId: 6318257479bcbf779df08816, isShown: false}]

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `snapchatReply[a]['isShown']` to change variable inside map inside the list, you should pass new variable to it, try this:

```
toggleReply(String commentId) {
    for (int a = 0; a < snapchatReply.length; a++) {
      print(snapchatReply.length);
      if (commentId == snapchatReply[a]['commentId']) {
        if (snapchatReply[a]['isShown'] == false) {
          setState(() {
            snapchatReply[a] = {
              'commentId': snapchatReply[a]['commentId'],
              'isShown': true
            };
          });
        } else {
          print("else");
          setState(() {
            snapchatReply[a] = {
              'commentId': snapchatReply[a]['commentId'],
              'isShown': false
            };
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

your main issue is every time you call `setstate` this:

```
snapchatReply.add({
                "commentId":widget.snapshot.comments[j].id,
                "isShown":false
                });
```

will call, so this is cause doubling you list length every time, what you need to do is, rest you list before it. so try call  `snapchatReply = [];` before returning your `ListView.builder`.

Comment: same result....

Comment: when I call this, the snapchatReply  length is always same length as before, maybe you are doing something wrong some where else.

Comment: how do you receive snapchatReply? could you please include that part to your question?

Comment: be for returning your ListView, try call this: snapchatReply = [];  your issue is when ever you call setstate, its add the same value before to snapchatReply. we need to reset it before returning list view.

Comment: after setstate the state is not changing

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: after calling the function the state value is same though condition are matched

Comment: did you try call snapchatReply = [] before returning list view?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247879/discussion-between-eamirho3ein-and-jeevan-shrestha).

Comment: Now state is changing but not rendering

Comment: could you please include your full code so I can regenerate the issue?

Comment: I have provided the full code

Comment: @JeevanShrestha where?